# React with Webpack-huge bundle sizes

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've got an app which is pretty basic, but the bundle size is 6.7MB in dev and 1.8MB in production. The lion's share (94%) is Node Modules. Is there a straightforward way to only bundle those modules which are required? I tried Webpack Node Externals, but that broke everything-the app didn't know what 'require' meant anymore, for instance. I'm using Webpack 3.8. Here are my config files:

webpack.config:

```
const loaders = require('loaders');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
var Visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.js.map'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            loaders.css,
            loaders.url,
            {
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    plugins: [
        new CompressionPlugin({
            asset: '[path].gz[query]',
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.eot?.+$|\.ttf?.+$|\.woff?.+$|\.svg?.+$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
        }),
        new Visualizer()
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './'
    }
};
```

webpack.production.config:

```
// Webpack config for creating the production bundle.

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var writeStats = require('./util/writeStats');
var strip = require('strip-loader');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

var assetsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../static/dist');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
    entry: {
        main: './src/client.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: assetsPath,
        filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: [strip.loader('debug'), 'babel?stage=0&optional=runtime']
            }
        ]
    },
    progress: true,
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['src', 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['*', '.json', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        // new webpack.DefinePlugin({__CLIENT__: true, __SERVER__: false}),

        // ignore dev config
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\.\/dev/, /\/config$/),

        // set global vars
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                // Mainly used to require CSS files with webpack, which can happen only on browser
                // Used as `if (process.env.BROWSER)...`
                BROWSER: JSON.stringify(true),

                // Useful to reduce the size of client-side libraries, e.g. react
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),

        // optimizations
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            asset: '[path].gz[query]',
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.eot?.+$|\.ttf?.+$|\.woff?.+$|\.svg?.+$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
        }),

        // stats
        function() {
            this.plugin('done', writeStats);
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Webpack should bundle only the stuff you use by default from the require/import statement. I would use a bundle analyser to check that only the needed stuff are included. e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer If the bundle size can't be reduced, other strategies such as runtime load module on demand could be applied. Dividing the 1 big file to many smaller files.

Comment: @Kunukn good point. It looks like there are a few libraries which I am importing wholesale for the sake of a few functions. Perhaps there is a tool that automatically does tree shaking to only import the necessary ones?

Comment: if you have webpack2 the uglify plugin should do the tree shaking for you. I think this does require the node module in question to be structured to be able to take advantage of tree shaking, however.